# how to combine keys of a dictionary when the values are the same?

Tags: python

I am trying to combine the keys of a dictionary when the values are the same as below,I am trying as below it only prints the values of the dictionary, any guidance how to fix this?

```
final_BATS_container_id_list = [
    {'Rome_Nightly': ['15715489']},
    {'Rome': ['15715490']},
    {'Italy': ['15715491']},
    {'Paris': ['15715491']},
    {'France': ['15715491']},
    {'Italy_Escape': ['15715493']},
    {'Paris_Escape': ['15715493']},
    {'France_Escape': ['15715493']}]

new_key = ''

for BATS_container_id_dict in final_BATS_container_id_list:
    for key,value in BATS_container_id_dict.items():
        print('key %s => value %s'%(key,value))
```

Expected output:-

```
[{'Rome_Nightly': ['15715489']},
 {'Rome': ['15715490']},
 {'Italy/Paris/France': ['15715491']},
 {'Italy_Escape/Paris_Escape/France_Escape': ['15715493']}]
```

Comment: Your values are lists, but seem to always have a single value. Is that always true?

Comment: What have you tried? That code doesn't even come close to the desired result. Are you familiar with [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)? Or if the inputs might be unsorted, do you know how to use a dict as a collector in a loop?

Comment: @Mark - yes ,its always a list with single value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to invert the key/value relationship and accumulate the keys that are associated with values. Then a simple list comprehension will make the desired list of dicts for you:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [
    {'Rome_Nightly': ['15715489']},
    {'Rome': ['15715490']},
    {'Italy': ['15715491']},
    {'Paris': ['15715491']},
    {'France': ['15715491']},
    {'Italy_Escape': ['15715493']},
    {'Paris_Escape': ['15715493']},
    {'France_Escape': ['15715493']}]

groups = defaultdict(list)

for d in l:
    for k, v in d.items():
        groups[v[0]].append(k)

result = [{'/'.join(v): [k]} for k, v in groups.items()]
```

Giving you a `result` of:

```
[{'Rome_Nightly': ['15715489']},
 {'Rome': ['15715490']},
 {'Italy/Paris/France': ['15715491']},
 {'Italy_Escape/Paris_Escape/France_Escape': ['15715493']}]
```

Comment: If you'd like, you could use unpacking to get the first value: `for k, (v0,) in d.items(): groups[v0]...` This also acts like an assertion that the list length is 1.

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice suggestion @wjandrea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
final_BATS_container_id_list =  [
    {'Rome_Nightly': ['15715489']}, 
    {'Rome': ['15715490']}, 
    {'Italy': ['15715491']}, 
    {'Paris': ['15715491']}, 
    {'France': ['15715491']}, 
    {'Italy_Escape': ['15715493']}, 
    {'Paris_Escape': ['15715493']}, 
    {'France_Escape': ['15715493']}
]

value_map = {}
for item in final_BATS_container_id_list:
    for key, value in item.items():
        first = value[0] # eg. ['15715493'][0]. caution: index out of bounds
        vv = value_map.get(first, [])
        vv.append(key)
        value_map[first] = vv

result = []
for key in value_map.keys():
    joined = '/'.join(value_map[key]) # eg. Italy/Paris/France
    result.append({joined: [key]})

print(result)
```